# React Navigation change custom header title on componentDidMount

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm developing an app which has a tabNavigator and for each tab it has a stackNavigator with a custom header. From one of the screen I need to be able to pass a param to the stackNavigator to change the header title.

MyScreen.js:

```
class MyScreen extends Component {
    state = {
        title: "My Title"
    }

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const appToolbarTitle = navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.title
                ? navigation.state.params.title
                : "";
        console.log("NAV_PARAM: " + appToolbarTitle);
        return {
            header: props => {
                <AppToolbar title={appToolbarTitle} />;
            }
        };
    };

    setScreenTitle = title => {
        const { setParams } = this.props.navigation;
        setParams({ title: title });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.title != null && this.state.title != undefined) {
            this.setScreenTitle(this.state.title);
        }
    }

    ....

}
```

AppToolbar.js:

```
const appToolbar = props => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.toolbar}>
            <Text style={styles.toolbarTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={...}>
                <Icon
                    name="ios-contact"
                    color="grey"
                    size={30}
                    style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0, marginRight: 10 }}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};
```

For some reason the console.log statement prints correctly the param thats passed in componentDidMount but it seems its not getting through to the  component, any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you a missing a return here

```
header: props => {
               return  (<AppToolbar title={appToolbarTitle} />);
            }
```

or just

`header: props =>  <AppToolbar title={appToolbarTitle} />`

Comment: tried them and nothing... its like its not even using the AppToolbar component =/

Comment: Did you try with a simple `<Text>` header?

Comment: just tested it, it doesn't do anything... it just ignores it =/

Comment: It means the problem doesn't come from bind data. Maybe custom header doesn't work